# Call Method in Linq Queries

Tags: kendo-grid

I Use KendoUI Grid and I have a code like this :

```
 IQueryable<ListStatus> liststatus = (from karfarmalist in db.PTStbLists
 join eventlist in db.PTStbListEvents on karfarmalist.Id equals eventlist.SerialList 
 join combobase in db.GlbTbComboBases on eventlist.EventType equals combobase.GUID
 where karfarmalist.TFN.Equals(tfn) && karfarmalist.GuidList == listid
 select new ListStatus{
                       id = eventlist.Id,
                       eventdate = Farab.Utility.PersianDate.Georgian_jalali(eventlist.EventDate),
                       status = combobase.FAName
                      }).OrderBy(l => l.id);
```

Farab Call Raise an error. I use AsEnumerable method but orderby has error. How can I call that method in LINQ without error?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.ToList()` at the end of the query but that would cause a call to be made to the db, which will affect performance of the query. Not sure if this is what you want but you can give it a try.

Comment: I want to call Farab.Utility.PersianDate.Georgian_jalali(eventlist.EventDate).

Comment: If you add .ToList() at the end (after the OrderBy does it still Raise an error? and if so can you copy paste the exception in your question? That way we can know what might the problem be